# Visual studio files cannot be moved to other locations without the script dissapearing

Tags: visual-studio

Let me explain

I'm currently studying python at my school and need to send my files to my teacher, I have one slight pretty huge problem with that however. Whenever I move my files to a different location and then open it again, it opens, but I can't see the script at all, It's just blank. The script however works when I start it. Same thing happens when i send them. In worst case I need to change program. But I really like visual studio. ;(

anything would help, 
cheers

Comment: Any chance the script was added with a relative path outside of your project root, or with an absolute path outside of your project root? In both cases, if you copy or zip-up the project, the script would disappear.

Comment: Try removing the script from your project and adding it again.

Comment: So there is no way of sending the file over internet?

Comment: Of course there is. But it must be part of the set of files that you send over.

Comment: Right, so what file am i supposed to move in that case?

Comment: How am I supposed to say with the limited amount of information you've given us to work with.